# Getting "GetPrimaryCpuAbi task failed Unexpectedly." every time even if I try to build a simple android app on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using:

> VS Community 2015 edition, Xamarin v4.2, Xamarin.Android v7

It Shows:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): error MSB4018: The "GetPrimaryCpuAbi" task failed unexpectedly.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): error MSB4018: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MSBuildExtensions' from assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GetPrimaryCpuAbi.Execute()

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(283,2): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is clean your Xamarin project. menu Build > Clean all